# Shared (Web-Farm) ASP.NET Web Two-Tiered Environment

Tags: asp.net, session, affinity

If you using a F5 load balancer (sticky sessions) in front of the web-tier, can I have a shared two-tiered web application environment that can have web-applications with two different session management configurations?  For example, web app # 1 uses In-Process session management and web app # 2 uses a separate session state server?  Both web application sit in IIS in the web-tier and database sitting in the data tier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the type of session management you use is determined/set per web app. There's no requirement that multiple apps on the same server (or AppPool) use the same scheme.

With sticky sessions, each client will always be connected to the same server / web app instance, so you could even have web app #1 on server #1 use InProc, and web app #1 on server #2 use StateServer. Not recommended, of course (nor are sticky sessions), but possible.

Comment: To clarify, sticky sessions load balancer is not recommended with StateServer session managament?  Only InProc session management is recommended for sticky sessions load balancer?

Comment: Sticky sessions are *required* with InProc session management, but not with StateServer or SQL Server (provided all machines in the web farm are pointing to the same session store, of course). The problem with sticky sessions is that they defeat two major benefits of load balancing: full recovery in the event of a server failure, and true, scalable "load balancing."